# How Would I Set Mouse Cursor At X,Y Coordinates, Click Left Mouse And Scroll Left,Right,Top,Bottom

Tags: c#

As described in the title I've been trying to search for a way to set the mouse coordinates by using a `Cursor.Position = new Point(58, 128);` Then while holding the Left Mouse button (Down) I'm trying to scroll to another direction(random direction). For example, if I was to go onto Google Earth and set the cursor position at `0,0` the cursor would then scroll around the map. If anyone can help out I would surely appreciate it.

Thanks

Solution: floatas, thanks again  for responding to this post. I spent yesterday and today trying to figure this out and I finally got it working. I will post my code in hopes this helps others out.

Comment: Can you not work at a higher, more semantic level? I.e. using the [UI Automation Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) or an exposed API?

Comment: Pleaes @JordanMiller, do not edit a question to put the answer inside. If necessary, post yourself an answer and then validate it. Don't update title neither.

Comment: @jordan Please read the [faq] before continuing to use SO. This is *not* a forum and the rules a completely different. If you want to answer your own question, then post an answer. The checkmark next to an answer is used to select the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm new to this so I apologies if I'm doing this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to import some functions.

To change cursor position:

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(
        [In] int X,
        [In] int Y);
```

To simulate mouse events:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(
    [In] uint dwFlags,
    [In] uint dx,
    [In] uint dy,
    [In] int dwData,
    [In] uint dwExtraInfo);
```

Possible mouse events:

```
public enum MouseEvents
{
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02,
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04,
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08,
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10,
    MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
}
```

You can send mouse down and mouse up, simulating click:

```
mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | (uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
```

Didn't tested this, but should press mouse, drag and release:

```
mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
SetCursorPos((int)X+10, (int)Y+10);
mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X+10, Y+10, 0, 0);
```